# Use Matplotlib to plot markers where the y coordinate is a string?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot individual markers [x,y] where x = a number and y = a string in python.

For example, the code below attempts to plot markers on a series of lines but generates an error because the y argument is a string. The code 'works' if the y argument is an integer but doesn't map to the other lines :

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

data = [    (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), 'sleep'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'eat'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 2, 0), 'work'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'sleep'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'eat'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'work')
        ]

events = [
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), 'sleep'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), 'eat'),
            (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'work'),
    ]

colormapping = {"sleep" : "C0", "eat" : "C1", "work" : "C2"}

#plt.plot([data[0][0], data[0][1]],['one','one'])
#plt.plot([data[1][0], data[1][1]],['two','two'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for d in data:
    plt.plot([d[0],d[1]], [d[2],d[2]], linewidth=5, color=colormapping[d[2]], zorder = 1)
    #plt.scatter([d[0],d[1]], [d[2],d[2]], color='purple', zorder =10)

for e in events:
    plt.plot(e[0],e[1])

plt.ylabel('some numbers')


ax.autoscale()
#loc = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,15,30,45])
loc = mdates.DayLocator(interval=1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
ax.grid('on')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `plt.plot` accepts lots of different ways to be called, it gets confused when the second parameter is a string and tries to interpret it as a marker format. The solution is to surround it with a list or an array.

From [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) note the call signatures:

```py
plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

To distinguish whether the user intents `plot(x, y)` versus`plot(y, fmt)`, it makes sense to check whether the second parameter is a string or not. This doesn't work when `y` would be a single string, but can be worked around by creating a list.

Also note that the default format for `plt.plot` is a line, which is invisible if there is only one point. So, either a marker format should be specified, or `plt.scatter(e[0], e[1])` should be called.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

data = [(dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), 'sleep'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'eat'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 2, 0), 'work'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'sleep'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 15), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'eat'),
        (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 45), 'work')]
events = [(dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 30), 'sleep'),
          (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 0, 45), 'eat'),
          (dt.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 1, 30), 'work')]
colormapping = {"sleep": "C0", "eat": "C1", "work": "C2"}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for d in data:
    plt.plot([d[0], d[1]], [d[2], d[2]], linewidth=5, color=colormapping[d[2]], zorder=1)
for e in events:
    plt.plot([e[0]], [e[1]], "ro")

plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]